# How can I schedule python script in the cloud?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, data-pipeline

I am developing a python script that downloads some excel files from a web service. These two files are combined with another one stored in my computer locally to produce the final file. This final file is loaded to some database and PowerBI dashboard to finally visualize data.

My question is: How can I schedule this to run it daily if my computer is turned off? As I said, two files are web scraped (so no problem to schedule) but one file is stored locally.

One solution that comes to my mind: Store the local file in Google Drive/OneDrive and download it with the API so my script is not dependent of my computer. But if this was the case, how can I schedule that? What service would you use? Heroku,...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am running the schedule package for exactly something like that.
It’s easy to setup and works very well.

Comment: but that depends on your computer to be turned on, right?

Comment: heroku, upload your local script and run the schedule package there

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure about your context, but I think you could look into using AWS Lambda for this. It is reasonably easy to set it up and also create a schedule for running code.

It is even easier to achieve this using the [serverless framework](https://www.serverless.com/). [This link](https://www.serverless.com/examples/aws-python-scheduled-cron/) shows an example built with Python that will run on a schedule.

Comment: I have found pythonanywhere.com which is free for one task. I'll try with that one.. if I need more capabilities I'll go with AWS